# Mostrar repeticiones de un valor en un array en c

Tags: c

Estoy intentando contabilizar los valores que se repiten en una matriz de dos dimensiones. La relleno con números aleatorios y la muestro correctamente, pero cuando intento mostrar el número de veces que se repite un valor en la tabla, solo accedo a la dirección en memoria pero no al valor en si.

¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

Un saludo y gracias de antemano.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    int tabla[3][3];
    int i, j, numero, rep;

    srand(time(NULL));

    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            tabla[i][j] = rand()%11;
        }
    }

    printf("\n");

    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            printf("%3d", tabla[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n\n");

    printf("Introduce un número para ver cuantas veces se repite:");
    scanf("%d", &numero);

    rep = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            if(tabla[i][j] == numero) rep++;
        }
    }

    printf("\nEl número %d se repite %d veces.\n\n", numero, rep);
    
    return 0;
}
```

La salida siempre es 0 para el número de repeticiones, aunque el número se repita varias veces.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido al sitio. Por favor, intenta proporcionar un [mcve] para facilitar que otros puedan ayudarte. Un saludo.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Ya he puesto el programa completo. Un saludo.

Comment: A primera vista el programa parece correcto. Es un poco raro lo del `rand()%11` (¿no sería `rand%10` o `(rand % 10) + 1`?) pero eso no afecta a que el programa funcione. ¿Has intentado usar un depurador para ver cómo se ejecuta línea a línea? O al menos, poner un `printf` dentro del bucle final para ver si entra dentro de `rep++` o no, y qué valores tiene.

Comment: De hecho, aquí funciona: https://onlinegdb.com/rJBXGzqe_

Comment: Gracias por las respuestas. Me apunto el consejo sobre rand() ;). He probado poner un `printf("%d\n", tabla[i][j]);` antes del `if()` y me devuelve un entero de 9 o 10 dígitos. Estoy compilando en una máquina virtual con Debian 10 y gcc 8.3.0.

Comment: El problema está en el sistema, no se cual es, pero ahí está. En Ubuntu con gcc, CentOs con gcc o Visual Studio no ha dado ningún problema. Gracias por su tiempo. Un saludo.